# Classifying change based on date and section in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Date    Tag     Section
1/21/22     001     1
1/22/22     001     2
1/23/22     001     3
1/21/22     002     2
1/22/22     002     1
1/23/22     002     2", header = TRUE)
```

The dataframe has already been grouped by Tag number and date from oldest to newest. My objective is to see if the object with the tag number is moving or staying in the same section, moving up sections or moving down sections between dates. In this case moving from 1 to 2 would be moving up and moving from 2 to 1 would be down.

A new column could have no movement for the first observation of the tag it is in but would have movement for the next two dates. All tag numbers are unique values. I have been thinking about dplyr statement or and if statement but have not been able to come up with anything.

Comment: You could probably use the difference between section and lag(section).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case_when` to check many different conditions in an easy to read way:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Movement = case_when(
      lag(Section) > Section ~ "Down",
      lag(Section) < Section ~ "Up",
      TRUE ~ "No Movement"), .by = Tag)

# Output:
     Date Tag Section    Movement
1 1/21/22   1       1 No Movement
2 1/22/22   1       2          Up
3 1/23/22   1       3          Up
4 1/21/22   2       2 No Movement
5 1/22/22   2       1        Down
6 1/23/22   2       2          Up
```